# Can you change dark blue selection colour in input field with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the dark blue selection colour of an input with CSS?

I'm aware of the following, but these will not change the inner selection of text in a text field or drop down.

```
::selection
::-moz-selection
::-webkit-selection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is an operating system setting that you simply can't control.